# Failed to import bridging header '/MyProject-Bridging.h'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, bridging-header

I use an objective c framework (CardIO) in my Swift project
When I run my tests without import my target everything going Okay
Then When I import my Target it pops

```
@testable import MyProject
```

Failed to import bridging header '/Users/**/workspace/MyProject-Bridging.h'
and MyProject-Bridging.h pop an error
`'CardIO/CardIo.h'` file not found

> > >
> >     I added the bridging header path in SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER under my target

Answer (score 1):

after many days digging in the internet.. the problem wan in CardIO, 
change the import line from

```
#import <CardIO/CardIo.h>
```

to

```
#import "CardIO.h"
@import AudioToolbox;
@import AVFoundation;
@import CoreMedia;
@import CoreVideo;
@import MobileCoreServices;
```

if the error of "framework not found" popped only in the test target, you should add it to test target